# Short freezes when having both NVME SSD and nVidia NVS 300

Tags: windows-7, freeze

I have a P9D-MV motherboard which I use in a desktop PC paired with Intel Xeon E3-1231 v3. I installed windows on  an Intel 750 400GB SSD. I had to add NVME module in bios to enable boot. It worked fine with the integrated video card, but once I put the **nVidia  NVS 300** I notice short freezes - around quarter to half a second, sometimes even one second. **The freezes happen ONLY in Google Chrome** sometimes when I move the mouse over a link or it tries to show suggestions while I type. But in general I didn't have much time to notice a definite pattern when the freezes occur. I moved the mouse from the hub to a port directly on the board (because I thought it's just the mouse freezing). It didn't solve the problem. I'm still not 100% sure if everything on the screen is freezing or the mouse only or just the IO (SSD). I'll do bore testing and I'll update the question.

The video is on x8 lane (x16 physical) slot, the ssd is on x4 slot through PCIe to M.2 adapter, then connects to the SSD using the original m.2 to U2 cable. I've used the ssd for years on another PC - no problems with it.

I couldn't swear on the video though. I bought 3 of them because they can drive two monitors and are low power - ideal for the office. I didn't notice problems with it on another machine, although it's not physically the same card - it's another one of the same model.

The problem doesn't exist on remote desktop. So it shouldn't be related to the SSD. Although the ssd speed is quite inconsistent - 700 to 1500 MB/s. I think it was better when using the internal video.

I'll try swapping them around and switching back to the built in ASpeed Video Adapter to see if the problem presists.

**UPDATE:**
I worked for a while on the PC. I only notice this on Google Chrome. The freezes happen when I hover a link, when I start typing or when I open new tab. That's 10-30% of the time. It's a new fresh install of windows and chrome. Latest updates installed. I will try to reinstall chrome... On the other hand it doesn't happen on remote desktop.

**UPDATE2:**
I setup a RAM disk for chrome cache directory and the freezes still happen.

The SSD:
[image]

The M.2 to U.2 cable that comes with the drive:
[image]

The PCIe adapter:
[image]

Comment: “the ssd is on x4 slot through PCIe to M.2 adapter, then connects to the SSD using the original m.2 to U2 cable.” - What?

Comment: That's how I reacted when I first saw this SSD. It was a replacement for a defective SATA SSD. I didn't know where to plug it... I posted pictures of all the accessories. It worked for a long time like this on another machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have yet to confirm that, but the problem seams that I ask too much of the NVIDIA NVS 300. It is PCIe Gen 1 which is already relatively slow, but putting it in a x8 slot (there is no option in bios to configure it to x16) makes it struggle with two monitors.
Interestingly enough GT9600 which is PCIe Gen 2 still has this problem. **Moving to GTX 550 TI fixed the problem.** Or at least I haven't noticed any freezes for the last 3-4 hours. I'll come back in a few days to report.

I guess Google Chrome uses a lot more graphic power than I thought.

**Update. Confirmed - Installing better graphic card fixes the problem.** I have no idea why this problem happens. Could be related to NVME being on PCIe and running different revisions of PCIe SSD on PCIe 3.0 and video on PCI 1/2. It's strane that both GT9600  and GTX550 run on PCIe Gen 2 but only GTX550 runs smoothly. Also I never noticed GT9600 causing freezs on older machine with SATA disk.